# Next select options from database based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

In a jsp page there are more than two select boxes depending on the first selected option the data base is queried to display the next selectable options and so on. How to achieve this dynamic selection using JQuery or AJAX or any thing else?

The typical jsp page

```
<!--Data base connections are done here-->
<%!

    Connection con=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rs1=null;
    String driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String query1=null;

%>

<%
try{
    Class.forName(driver);
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:guest","username","password"); 
    stmt=con.createStatement(); 
    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
%>

<!--Selection box 1-->

Select X value:
<select name="x" id='x'>                                            
<%  
    try
    {
        query1= "select x from TableA";

        rs1=stmt.executeQuery(query1);

    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

while(rs1.next()){ 
String x=rs1.getString(1);%>    
<option value="<%=x%>"><%=x%></option>
<%} %>
</select>

<!--Selection box 2-->

Select Y value:
<select name="y" id='y'>                                            
<%  
    try
    {
        query1= "select y from TableB where TableB.x=VALUE OF X BEEN SELECTED;

        rs1=stmt.executeQuery(query1);

    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

while(rs1.next()){ 
String y=rs1.getString(1);%>    
<option value="<%=y%>"><%=y%></option>
<%} %>
</select>
```

Comment: If you want to do this without any postback, javascript/jQuery and AJAX are indeed a good start. Please try to write some code and come back to SO if you get stuck with it. Hopefully you can find quite a lot of info on that pattern online.

Comment: You can achieve this in multiple way like just using javascript or Jquery etc.